# How can I give a different class for each header in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been trying to make a HTML page where each box represents 1 item that has been ordered. Here's the HTML for the box:

```
<div id="boxMaster" class="small-box bg-info" class="box-PEDIDO" hidden>
      <a class="nmroPedido small-box-header" id="header"></a> <a class="float-right" id="dataEntrega">28/09/2021
        16:00</a>
      <hr>

      <div class="inner">
        
        <p id="nomeproduto"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="carrinho"></i>
      </div>
      <hr id="footer" class="baixoHr">
      <a href="#" class="small-box-footer"> Fruta > Tropical > Manga > Tommy   

      </a>
    </div>
```

And this is how I'm treating the data to feed it:

```
fetch('http://---.--.14.--:--/pedidos/', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NCwiaWF------yNTkwLCJleHAiOjE2MzM3Nzg5OTB9.XwrGFhLiGJ0YS5FHjn7Xo',
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  }

})
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();


  })
  .then(function (jsonResponse) {
    // console.log(jsonResponse);
    var DadosPedidos = jsonResponse;
    pedidosArray = jsonResponse.length;








    for (let pedidos of DadosPedidos) {
      let a = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < pedidos.items.length; i++) {

        let pedidosLength = pedidos.items.length;
        let lengthPedidos = pedidos.nroPedCliente;
       




        var boxClonado = $("#boxMaster").clone(true);
        $(boxClonado).appendTo("#preparando").removeAttr("hidden", "style").removeAttr("id").addClass(`${pedidos.id}-${pedidos.items[i].codItem}`);

        $(".nmroPedido").addClass(`${pedidos.items[i].codItem}`);



        let nomeClasses = `${pedidos.id}-${pedidos.items[i].codItem}`;
        let h3quantidade = `${pedidos.id}-${pedidos.items[i].codItem}`;









        $("." + nomeClasses).append(`<p>${pedidos.items[i].codItem}</p>`);
        $("." + h3quantidade).append(`<h3 class="h3qtd">${pedidos.items[i].qtdPedida}</h3>`);
        //$("." + headerPedido).append(`Nº do Pedido: ${pedidos.nroPedido}`);



        let data = new Date((pedidos.dataEntrega).substring(0, 10));
        let dataEnt = ((data.getDate())) + "/" + ((data.getMonth() + 1)) + "/" + data.getFullYear();
        



      }
    }
```

As you can see, I managed to give a unique class to each box (that represent 1 item) at the end of the line:

```
$(boxClonado).appendTo("#preparando").removeAttr("hidden", "style").removeAttr("id").addClass(`${pedidos.id}-${pedidos.items[i].codItem}`);
```

And also managed to do it for the quantities as well. The point is, I'm not being able to do it with the <a class="nmroPedido" id="header>, as the code is printing all `-${pedidos.items[i].codItem}` codItem all at once in the same class, for every <a id="header> there is. Therefore, I can't set individual "nroPedido" for the box header.

Here's the array I'm getting from the fetch, in case that helps:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui9cs.jpg

What am I missing? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. Just as example. You have a nested Object and you have to iterate through it with two each loops. Then you can append different unique id's. Then it's easy to create the correct HTML by JSON.

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters": {
      "batter": [{
          "id": "1001",
          "type": "Regular"
        },
        {
          "id": "1002",
          "type": "Chocolate"
        },
        {
          "id": "1003",
          "type": "Blueberry"
        },
        {
          "id": "1004",
          "type": "Devil's Food"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Raised",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters": {
      "batter": [{
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular"
      }]
    },

  },
  {
    "id": "0003",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Old Fashioned",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters": {
      "batter": [{
          "id": "1001",
          "type": "Regular"
        },
        {
          "id": "1002",
          "type": "Chocolate"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

//console.log(arr);

var markup = '';

$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
  key = key + 1;
  markup += '<a class="nmroPedido-' + key + ' small-box-header" id="header-' + key + '"></a> <a class="float-right" id="dataEntrega">' + value.id + '</a>'
  $.each(value.batters.batter, function(key, v) {
    //console.log('id', v.id);
    markup += ' <div class="inner"><p id="nomeproduto">' + v.type + '</p></div>';
  });
});
$('#boxMaster').append(markup);
//console.log(markup);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxMaster"></div>
```

Comment: That does kind of work! Big help already! But I'm getting only 0's and 1's as the names.
Right now I have 8 items, so 8 boxes. 
How can i make it so it goes like nmroPedido-1, nmroPedido-2, nmroPedido-3, 4, and so on?

Comment: Ok now I understand you. You like to create the boxes with JQuery.

Comment: Updated my answer. Did a small example how you can iterate through your Objects. Thx for upvoting :-)